# Depending fields validation

Tags: cxjs

I have two password fields that, among other rules, have to be equal for the form to be valid.

```
<form onSubmit="resetPassword">
    <ValidationGroup valid-bind="$page.formvalid"  >
        <FlexCol>
            <TextField
                value-bind="$page.password1"
                label="Password 1"
                inputType="password"
                required
                validationRegExp={/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/}
                minLength="6"
                onValidate="validatePasswordsEqual"
            />
            <TextField
                value-bind="$page.password2"
                label="Password 2"
                inputType="password"
                required
                validationRegExp={/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/}
                minLength="6"
                onValidate="validatePasswordsEqual"
            />
            <Button
                submit
                disabled-expr="!{$page.formvalid}"
                text="Reset Password"
            />
        </FlexCol>
    </ValidationGroup>
</form>
```

However, the `validatePasswordsEqual` runs only for the currently edited field, leaving the other field always unequal. I tried using `store.notify()` from inside the `validatePasswordsEqual`, but without success.

How can I cause validation on both fields at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `validationParams` field to trigger the validation if a value in another field changes.

```
<TextField
   value-bind="$page.password1"
   label="Password 1"
   inputType="password"
   validationParams={{ password2: { bind: '$page.password2 }}
   required
   validationRegExp={/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/}
   minLength="6"
   onValidate="validatePasswordsEqual"
/>
```

The third argument provided to the `onValidate` callback will be the calculated value of `validationParams`.